# dragging label/button/textield to another view

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, uilabel, iphone-5

There are two views. in first view i created label,textfield,button . how can user drag that label/textfield/button to 2nd view and edit label name and size ,button name and size, textfield size/add placeholder.

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creted label,textfield and button programatically and added them to view1 as subviews.Upto  this correct but how can you drag them to view2 ?
They are not visible in xib file.So it is not possible to drag objects created programatically from one view to another view.You do one thing,add them as subviews to view2 .

Comment: Ok. If i will add label,textfield and button in xib file. Is it Possible ,in which user can drag and edit label, button and textfield from one view to another. If possible , then please give me small hints on it.